# How to generate pdf file on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'am using visual studio 2008. I wants to generate pdf file on button click. I have used

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

but it shows an error

```
The type or namespace name iTextSharp could not be found (are you missing a using        directive or an assembly reference?
```

from searching I have found that , need to add a source assembly (iTextSharp.dll) . How will it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This is unneccessarily complicated. As CodeCaster points out [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19857331/1344058), you can just use NuGet to install iTextSharp. I'd recommend you try that.

You need to download the iTextSharp library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ and reference that .dll in VS. Your download will be a zip file with multiple other archives in it. From those, chose `itextsharp-dll-core.zip` and extract it.

Then you go into Visual Studio, right click your project and chose "Add reference...". In the following dialog you select the dll. Now you can use `using iTextSharp;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/).

Comment: Okay, that's easier than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download this dll.
So download and then add a reference in your project and then you can use the same.
Like Right click on the Project > Add Reference >

1) A new window will open and you can add the file.

2) Build and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason for failure:**

you did not add `ItextSharp.DLL` as reference to your project. untill unless you add this dll to you project you can not use the classes from `ITextSharp` Library.

**Solution:**
you need to download `ItextSharp.DLL` and Add that dll as reference to your Projet.

**Step 1:** : Download `ItextSharp.DLL` from below Link.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

**Step 2:**
right click on Project Select -> `Add Reference`

**Step 3:**
Select `ItextSharp.Dll` from your downloaded location.

**Step 4:**
Now Rebuild the project.